How do you resolve permission issues when deploying an Azure App Service using Azure DevOps?
We have a pretty basic NodeJS Express application that we package in a docker container and publish to an Azure Container Registry using an Azure DevOps build pipeline. This part works fine, but when we run a task to make our App Service use this newly published image we get permission issues.
We are using the following command to activate the image in our App Service in our build pipeline:
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: ${{ variables.service_connection }}
              appName: ${{ variables.app_name }}
              imageName: ${{ variables.container_registry }}/${{ variables.image_name }}:${{ parameters.stack }}

Our build pipeline is also running successfully. But when looking into my App Service it says that my application is unhealthy. When reading the logs it says:
2024-07-17T13:13:53.610Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"manifest for mycontainerrepository.azurecr.io/myimagename:my_tag not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by \"my_tag\" is not found"}
2024-07-17T13:13:53.784Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Head \"https://mycontainerrepository.azurecr.io/v2/myimagename/manifests/my_tag\": unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}
2024-07-17T13:13:53.788Z WARN  - Image pull failed. Defaulting to local copy if present.
2024-07-17T13:13:53.792Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)/home/LogFiles/2024_07_17_lw1sdlwk00013M_msi_docker.log  (https://myimagename.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_07_17_lw1sdlwk00013M_msi_docker.log) 

When looking the documentation from Microsoft we have found this:

The task uses the service principal in the service connection to authenticate with Azure. If the service principal has expired or doesn't have permissions to the App Service, the task fails with this error. Verify the validity of the service principal used and that it's present in the app registration. For more information, see Use role-based access control to manage access to your Azure subscription resources. This blog post also contains more information about using service principal authentication.

in this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-function-app-container-v1?view=azure-pipelines
It seems to hint that the Service Principle that is used by the Service Connection that our build pipeline is using must have the correct permissions. I have verified that it does have the AcrPull permission on the Azure Container Registry though (which seems to be what the logs are complaining about), it also has the Website Contributor role on the App Service we're deploying to.
My only way to repair this has been to go into Deployment Center and click "Disconnect" on the Azure Pipeline, and then manually configure that it should use the Azure Container Registry directly as source (the App Service has a managed Identity that has been given the AcrPull permission).
Can someone explain what the suggested way is to allow our Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy the new docker image to our App Service?
UPDATE
After some trial and error it seems the error is happening based on if we have configured Inbound IP restrictions or not. There are no outbound restrictions, but we have configured that only the health probe and some of our internal IPs should be able to access this service. If this restriction is disabled, then the image can suddenly be downloaded and things seems to work. Adding the restrictions again then keeps the service working up until the next time the Azure DevOps Pipeline does a deploy.
UPDATE 2: After adding our build agent to the whitelist I unfortunately still see the error logs:
2024-07-22T09:38:44.023Z INFO  - Pulling image: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/msitokenservice:stage5
2024-07-22T09:38:45.664Z INFO  - stage5 Pulling from appsvc/msitokenservice
2024-07-22T09:38:45.665Z INFO2024-07-22T09:39:09.382Z INFO  - Pulling image: containerrepo.azurecr.io/myimage:mytag
2024-07-22T09:39:09.861Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"manifest for containerrepo.azurecr.io/myimage:mytag not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by \"mytag\" is not found"}
2024-07-22T09:39:10.066Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Head \"https://containerrepo.azurecr.io/v2/myimage/manifests/mytag\": unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}
2024-07-22T09:39:10.068Z WARN  - Image pull failed. Defaulting to local copy if present.
2024-07-22T09:39:10.088Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)/home/LogFiles/2024_07_22_lw1sdlwk00013M_msi_docker.log  (https://myimage.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_07_22_lw1sdlwk00013M_msi_docker.log)Ending Log Tail of existing logs

After I make a request from one of my internal services I see the application start, but it seems to be with old application code:
2024-07-22T11:09:08.657Z INFO  - Pulling image: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/msitokenservice:stage5
2024-07-22T11:09:09.038Z INFO  - stage5 Pulling from appsvc/msitokenservice
2024-07-22T11:09:09.090Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:15c4360552ca5d886db18e4eaa6a95993305c67dae381aa8505592cd7c45bd46
2024-07-22T11:09:09.090Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/msitokenservice:stage5
2024-07-22T11:09:09.142Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Seconds
2024-07-22T11:09:10.461Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2024-07-22T11:09:10.462Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8081 --name myname .... mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/msitokenservice:stage5848eaf3c Downloading 3KB / 3KB
2024-07-22T11:09:26.039Z INFO  - 9d27848eaf3c Downloading 3KB / 3KB
2024-07-22T11:09:26.045Z INFO  - 9d27848eaf3c Verifying Checksum
2024-07-22T11:09:26.046Z INFO  - 9d27848eaf3c Download complete
2024-07-22T11:09:26.046Z INFO  - 9d27848eaf3c Extracting 3KB / 3KB
2024-07-22T11:09:26.085Z INFO  - 54a44433a92f Download complete
2024-07-22T11:09:26.094Z INFO  - 3f5e918ec666 Downloading 93B / 93B
2024-07-22T11:09:26.096Z INFO  - 3f5e918ec666 Verifying Checksum
2024-07-22T11:09:26.102Z INFO  - 3f5e918ec666 Download complete
2024-07-22T11:09:26.316Z INFO  - fac7f60f4c9d Downloading 1MB / 1MB
2024-07-22T11:09:26.478Z INFO  - fc36d29502d7 Downloading 136B / 136B
2024-07-22T11:09:26.479Z INFO  - fc36d29502d7 Verifying Checksum
2024-07-22T11:09:26.479Z INFO  - fc36d29502d7 Download complete
2024-07-22T11:09:26.538Z INFO  - 69ed387f9bce Download complete
...

I don't know if it's relevant here, but the service plan we use is defined by the following bicep:
resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  kind: 'app,linux'
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  tags: {
    costcenter: costcenter
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'S1'
  }
}


As per the error, have you firstly confirmed the target image(mycontainerrepository.azurecr.io/myimagename:my_tag) exists? If it does, try to recreate a new service connection and replace in task for a check. In addition, please show the code about how you defined the variables and parameters.

Yes, the image is verified to exist.
After some trial and error it seems the error is happening based on if we have Inbound IP restrictions or not. There are no outbound restrictions, but we have configured that only the health probe and some of our internal IPs should be able to access this service. If this restriction is disabled, then the image can suddenly be downloaded and things seem to work. Adding the restrictions again then keeps the service working.

Glad to know you have found the cause. You can answer yourself. In addition, you can get the agent ip and add it to exception, or use a self-hosted agent which has static IP which also can be added in exception, so the task is able to get the image.

Thank you @wadezhou-MSFT. I'm still having some issues with getting it to work, but I'll keep on trying to whitelist the build agent. Once I see a successful full flow I'll put this ticket as resolved.

Thank you for the info. If you still have any queries, you can update the ticket with problem detail or raise a new ticket, glad to help. :)

As per the error persists, i'm afraid the whiltelist is not correctly configured. After configuration, you can try to pull the image on agent directly for validation.

I think there's a missunderstanding here. The network restrictions that are applied are for the App Service. The Azure Container Registry has no applied IP restrictions. Yes, it's weird that an IP-restriction on the App Service should influence this Service's ability to fetch its image but it is the behavior we've seen. Our attempts to get a full picture on what's going on here continues. Further information is that the pipeline is updated to pring the IPv4 address of the build agent, and that's the same as our configured white list.

Thanks for the update. If it's caused by the network restrictions on app service, which disabled to pull image from ACR, add agent to whitelist won't work in this scenario. You can share how the network restriction is configured on app service, so we can check further. thanks.
